# What is the difference between Application.Windows() and Excel.Windows() in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, when should I use Application.Windows() and when should I use Excel.Windows()? Any code example would be specifically preferable.

Comment: What's the difference between maybe and perhaps?
I would say Excel.Windows and Application.WIndows is just the same.

Answer (score 3):

`Excel.Windows()` lets your write to it [1], whereas `Application.Windows()` is read-only [2] according to the documentation. [[1]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839584.aspx), [[2]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193325.aspx).

Other than the read-only distinction for the `Application` version, they are the same. So, if you're just reading properties, use the Application version, if you need to change something, use the `Excel` version.

Comment: @Jeeped I believe so? I'm honestly not 100% sure, and to be quite frank I don't think it really matters that much. VBA is kind of a mess, and I try to write the minimum amount required to accomplish a task. Background is mostly in server side web, but stuck doing VBA stuff for the summer.

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc: Sorry for jumping in between you two but why do you think VBA is a mess?

Comment: @SiddharthRout It just lacks a lot of features other languages have that I've become accustom to, and also does things very different than most other languages. I feel like Microsoft would be better off letting you use c# or one of the other .NET languages to do the application scripting, since those languages do things in more of a standard way. Visual Basic has a lot of ease of use things for non programmers, which is a bit frustrating for a dev to deal with.

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc - My apologies, `?excel.Windows.count` and `?application.Windows.count` both work in a new blank workbook's VBA Immediate window.

Comment: @Jeeped are you asking or making a statement?

Comment: @Jeeped Gottcha. Yeah, it should. My understanding is that the only difference is that the window objects in `application.windows` are read-only, and you're just reading with `.count`.

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc: I mostly work with Visual Basic. VB.Net/VB6/VBA/VBScript. I have been working with VBA for more than 15 years so trust me when I say VBA is not a mess :). Working with MS Office applications has never been so easy `if you know what you have to do`. Try automating Office from `.Net`. If you are a newbie to dot net, you will face hell automating it. VBA for MAC is what I would call a "Mess".

Comment: @SiddharthRout Perhaps it's an experience thing. Most of my background is in servers and web, so it's a big shift in thinking for me. However, I'm not really having big troubles, mostly frustrations with things not working the way I expect them to.

Comment: `...mostly frustrations with things not working the way I expect them to...` And hence I said in my previous comment `...if you know what you have to do...` Today if I work with servers and web, I am bound to face frustation when things do not work but that doesn't mean it is in a mess. Once in a while I come across people who pass this statement that "VBA is a mess" and (no offence) but that really ticks me off... :)

Answer (score 3):

The `Excel` library has classes named `Windows` and `Application`. Then `Excel.Windows` is the fully qualified name for the class `Windows`. Class `Application` has *property* named `Windows` which returns collection of the windows in all workbooks.

So you can use `Excel.Windows` when you want to refer to a class `Windows` and you will use `Application.Windows` *property* when you want to refer to windows objects. HTH.

In Object Browser we can see it:
[image]

---

There is problem with the naming. The name of class `Windows` and the property `Windows` are the same. All the following code examples refer to the same collection of window objects using the `Windows` property:

```
Dim eaw As Excel.Windows
Dim aw As Excel.Windows
Dim ew As Excel.Windows

Set eaw = Excel.Application.Windows
Set aw = Application.Windows
Set ew = Excel.Windows
```

The code `Set aw = Application.Windows` and `Set ew = Excel.Windows` are the same, because many of the properties and methods that return the most common objects can be used without the `Application` object qualifier. Properties and methods that can be used without the Application object qualifier are considered `global` and that is the case for `Windows` as well.

> In summary:

- When declaring a variable of type `Excel.Windows` you will not make any mistake when you take the fully qualified name e.g. `Dim wnds As Excel.Windows`.
- When referring to collection of window objects it is up to you which way you choose, all the following are equivalent (return the same collection) `Set eaw = Excel.Application.Windows`, `Set aw = Application.Windows`, `Set ew = Excel.Windows`. *Note: According to Object Browser of my Excel 2007 this collection is `read-only`.*